# What is the "VERSION" in "cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)”

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I know the meaning of below CMake statement:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
```

I am just wondering what the `VERSION` part is *syntactically*?

Is it a [unquoted argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#unquoted-argument)?  If it *is* an argument, there must be some other argument choices.

But according to [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html), it seems `VERSION` is the only choice for the `cmake_minimum_required()` command.

If so, why do we even need to specify this argument **explicitly**??

And according to [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_VERSION.html#variable:CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_VERSION), this command sets the variable CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_**VERSION**. Is there some kind of string **concatenation** here? So I can use `set_minimum_required(XXX <some_value>)` to sent an arbitrary variable with the name `CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_XXX` to <some_value>?

### ADD 1

I just tried with below statement in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(XXX 123)
```

And cmake complains that:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (cmake_minimum_required):
  cmake_minimum_required called with unknown argument "XXX".
```

So it seems to be an argument.

But according to [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#options) for the `project()` command, a similar `VERSION` string is designated as an **option**. Seems a bit inconsistent.

### ADD 2

I just tried with below statement in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(3.10)
```

And cmake complains that:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  cmake_minimum_required called with unknown argument "3.10".
```

So it seems CMake relies on the `VERSION` part to properly interpret the "3.10" argument. So I guess the `VERSION` is also an option here.

And since there's another possible option `FATAL_ERROR`, it is necessary to have a `VERSION` option.

**So to summarize my current understanding:**

The essential paradigm of CMake language is:

CMake commands just manipulate variables based on arguments and options.

Some variables are **required** to be manipulated and some are **optional**.

- For required ones, their values are specified through arguments. (kind of like positional argument)
- For optional ones, their values are specified through argument following corresponding options. (kind of like named argument)

### ADD 3

From [here](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics.html), for the `VERSION` in `cmake_minimum_required()`:

> The VERSION is a special **keyword** for this function. And the value of
> the version follows the keyword.

So here it is called *keyword* instead of *option* ...

### Add 4

[Some feelings](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9946490) about CMake...

Comment: *"Is it a unquoted argument? If it is an argument, there must be some other argument choices."* Yes, but I don't see how this necessarily results in there being other options. Maybe it's just there to add clarity, maybe the developers wanted to keep the possibility of adding other options in the future...

Comment: ＠fabian  Thanks for the comment. It's much better than a downvote without any comment. I just found CMake language is not very coherent. It demonstrates quite a bad practice of free will...

Comment: @fabian IMHO, an `argument` is more flexible than an `option`. But if there's only one purpose for a command, I think it should be neither `argument` nor `option`. But rather the command name should be changed to `cmake_minimum_required_version()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the input to a CMake command can be classified as 3 types:

1. keyword argument (also called [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#options))
2. positional argument
3. variable arguments (like `...` in C)

For 1, Like the `VERSION` in `cmake_minimum_required`, whose value follows it immediately. It is called [keyword](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics.html) or [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#options).

For 2, Such argument has a formal name and is referenced through that name within the command body.

For 3, the argument can be referenced with `ARGV`, `ARGN`, `ARGVC`.

I also see `marker argument` somewhere. But I forget where. Horrible syntax...

### ADD 1

OK I found the `marker argument`. It's in the book [Mastering CMake](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930934319) by the CMake team:

[image]
[image]

...while the CMake official document says it's an [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html):

> Search the paths specified by the PATHS **option** or in the short-hand
> version of the command. These are typically hard-coded guesses.

What a chaotic wording...

Answer (score 3):

> What is the "VERSION" in "cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)”
>
> I am just wondering what the VERSION part is syntactically?

A string. `VERSION`. Nothing special.

> Is it a unquoted argument?

Yes.

> why do we even need to specify this argument explicitly??

To preserve forward compatibility. The idea is that maybe in the feature there will be `cmake_minimum_required(DATE 2021-11-03)` or similar, for example.

> Is there some kind of string concatenation here?

No. [It is set explicitly](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmCMakeMinimumRequired.cxx#L70).

> So I can use set_minimum_required(XXX <some_value>) to sent an arbitrary variable with the name CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_XXX to <some_value>?

No.

> Some variables are required to be manipulated and some are optional.

CMake [argument parsing](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html) is really crude and simple. It's basically in shell pseudocode `if $1 == "VERSION" then check_version($2) else error`. How you call those strings is really up to your *interpretation* that depends on the context, in the context of `cmake_minimum_required`, sure `VERSION` is a "keyword". Or a "special required argument". Or similar.

All function arguments are strings, and functions compare them to other strings and execute logic upon that. There are no other variable types. Lists are strings, list elements are separated by `;` character in a string.

And the implementation of cmake_minimum_required is here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmCMakeMinimumRequired.cxx#L29 . Funny, it looks like the parsing is in a loop, so doing `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION VERSION VERSION VERSION 3.11)` works as fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's really great to know that interesting implementation...